# How to post an image link to Facebook feed using graph API

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm trying to post a picture to a feed using the graph API but this does not work if my image url does not have an image filename extension such as .png
(I have a URL to a png without the .png file extension as the image is created dynamically on the server)

This does seem to work when I manually post the link on my Facebook wall. Facebook wraps the URL like this:
http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAsdfyQsdfXvV5h59OP&w=90&h=90&url="my image url"

Does anyone know how I can post the URL of an image to the picture field of a feed post?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook downloads and caches any image posted on the wall. It is then distributed on their CDN (content delivery network).

The reason is simple: load times. If someone posts an image from a slow server on FB, this could make experience of Facebook slow. So they copy all that.

So

1. maybe Facebook still has an old copy. Try with a fresh URL.
2. can facebook access the URL, or only your user?

Comment: Facebook does not seem to accept an image URL sent to the feed in the picture field if it doesn't have an image filename extension.

Comment: Sam - Did you get an answer for this?
I'm having the same issue. I'm afraid Facebook don't accept it?
I get an exception 

"OAuthException: FBCDN image is not allowed in stream: http://vthumb.ak.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-ak-ash4/410445_146214702334395_12224595508739_3750_715_t.jpg"

Comment: I read that it can be done by using "object_attachment" parameter instead of "picture", but can't seem to specify the photo ID, seems like they allow it only for user album photos
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/